# Get values from 2 rows in one row

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one that holds code types and another where I save templates for a calendar.
Each template has a startday and an endday (monday - sunday)

Code-type table

```
ID -            Code Type - Name 
1  ---------    1111 -------Monday
2  ---------    1112 -------Tuesday
3  ---------    1113 -------Wednesday
4  ---------    1114 -------Thursday
5  ---------    1115 -------Friday
6  ---------    1116 -------Saturday
7  ---------    1117 -------Sunday
```

Template table

```
ID -  Name -       Startday -  Endday
1  ---  Work ----- 1111 -------1115 
1  -  Weekend -    1116 -------1117
```

Now I want to show via an sql statement a table that looks like this:

```
ID -  Name -     Startday -     Endday 
1  -- Work ----- Monday ------- Friday 
1  -  Weekend -  Saturday ----- Sunday
```

I tried to do it by using a join but I can only join on the code types and each row in my table that I want to achieve has 2 code types so it doesn't work. 
I also tried to do it via a CASE-statement but I can't make two cases for startday and endday)

Anybody an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: The expected result contains Sunday, a value not found in your tables... Have matching sample data and result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Code Type" table is rather ill-formatted.  This answers assumes that the `codetype` is actually unique, so it can be used for a `join`.

Your tables should be set up so `startday` and `endday` are linked to the `id` column, not to the `codetype` column -- presumably `id` is the primary key of the table.

With the assumption that `codetype` is unique, you just want two joins:

```
select t.id, t.name, cts.name as startdate, cte.name as endday
from template t join
     codetype cts
     on t.startday = cts.codetype join
     codetype cte
     on t.endday = cte.codetype;
```

Comment: Codetype is unique so this works perfect, thank you!